# How to build a query in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, definition-query

I am trying to build a query and filter some features (not selection).
This is my code:

```py
#Import the necessary classes
from qgis.core import QgsFeatureRequest, QgsExpression

# Create a QgsFeatureRequest object
request = QgsFeatureRequest()

# Set the filter expression
expression = QgsExpression("mrn-kriter = 'BODEN 02: Ackerzahl >= 80'")
request.setFilterExpression(expression.expression())

# Iterate through the features and perform an operation
layer = iface.activeLayer()  # Assuming there's an active layer in QGIS
for feature in layer.getFeatures(request):
    # Do something with the feature
    pass
```

There is no error but I don't know why it is not working. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show an example of your layers attribute table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fields name needs to be double quoted in `QgsExpression`.

Your python string expression is : `mrn-kriter = 'BODEN 02: Ackerzahl >= 80'`

But it needs to be : `"mrn-kriter" = 'BODEN 02: Ackerzahl >= 80'`

You can for example escape these character

```py
expression = QgsExpression("\"mrn-kriter\" = 'BODEN 02: Ackerzahl >= 80'")
```

Comment: the filter does not work

Comment: So there is something else wrong....

Comment: What if you set this expression as a filter via (assuming active Layer applies) `iface.activeLayer().setSubsetString("\"mrn-kriter\" = 'BODEN 02: Ackerzahl >= 80'")`

Comment: thank you for your comment. I could solve it.

Comment: Can you elaborate and explain how you solve it? If the answer helps you, please accept it so this question does not remains unanswered.